# Flutter + Firebase: How to set state on bool value in documents

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set the value of a variable based on the return value of a field (bool) in Firestore.

So far, this is what I have come up with;

First I call the method here;

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAdventureStatus();
  }
```

And this is the method.

```
Future getAdventureStatus() async {
Firestore.instance
    .collection('adventures')
    .document(widget.currentUser.id)
    .collection('user_adventures')
    .where('adventure_active', isEqualTo: 'false');
setState(() {
  adventureActive = true;
  print('${adventureActive.toString()}');
});}
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the most pragmatic way of doing this?

Comment: where u r calling this. This should be call on initState hook.

Comment: Im calling it on initState

Comment: More code please

Comment: that's everything.

Comment: This code doesn't appear to actually execute a query an look at the results.  `where()` returns a Query, but that query has no been executed yet, and there are no results yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just remove the set state call and set the bool to true direct.

Future getAdventureStatus() async {
Firebase.instance.document()
...
adventureActive = true;
}